# Two HDD and one VM

Tags: virtualbox, hard-disk, virtual-machine

I have two devices on my PC, i.e. `/dev/sda` (134GB used - 16GB available) and `/dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV` (500GB used - 3.5TB available). VirtualBox is installed on `/dev/sda`, but I want to create a Virtual Machine based on `/dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV` with VB. How can I do it? I didn't be able to do it so far?

```
┌─╼ [~]
└╼ df -h
Filesystem                   Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev                          34G     0   34G   0% /dev
tmpfs                        6.7G  2.7M  6.7G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root  151G  123G   21G  86% /
tmpfs                         34G   94M   34G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                        5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs                         34G     0   34G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                    705M  373M  282M  57% /boot
/dev/sda1                    511M  4.7M  507M   1% /boot/efi
/dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV    3.5T  601G  2.7T  18% /HFT
tmpfs                        6.7G   16K  6.7G   1% /run/user/121
tmpfs                        6.7G  180K  6.7G   1% /run/user/1000
/home/infinity/.Private      151G  123G   21G  86% /home/infinity
```

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you mean. Can you build a full answer how I can do it?

Comment: @dsstorefile1 I think the mount point is `/HFT` according to `df -h`. But if I place the VDI on `/HFT/Store/`, I got `Could not create the medium storage unit '/HFT/Store/NewVirtualDisk1.vdi'`. What is the best solution?

Comment: 1. Do you have rights to write in `/HFT/Store/`? 2. Do path `/HFT/Store/` exist?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you want to expose `/dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV` as the hard drive for the VM.

You can use `VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename /location/dataLV.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/mapper/dataVG-dataLV`

You will have to modify permissions either to the device file/add a udev rule or run VirualBox as root for this to be possible. (The former is preferred). Then you may attach /location/dataLV.vmdk as a SATA/IDE harddisk in VirtualBox.